# Reoccurring error message when I try to use java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My assignment was to write java code that compute changes to dollar, quarter, dime, nickel, and penny coins. I wrote out pseudocode to keep track of the logic chain; however, the system keeps giving me the following error message, which looks as if it can't recognize the imported java.util.Scanner:

```
run:
Enter bill value: 123
Enter item price in pennies: 12.1
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at computechange.ComputeChange.main(ComputeChange.java:26)
C:\Users\Anya\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Could someone help me understand what is the error?
Thank you,
Anya

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Enter item price in pennies: 12.1
```

You can have a fraction of a penny?

Anyway, your error. `nextInt` cannot capture fractional values, so don't use that if that's what you want to enter.

Comment: Gosh that was a stupid mistypo from me. All fixed! thank you so much!